# Glide, obtengo el mensaje de error: "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You must not call setTag() on a view Glide is targeting"

Tags: java, android, android-glide

Al tratar de cargar una imagen usando `Glide`, dentro de un ImageView, asegurando tener el path de la imagen en `urlImage` y la instancia del `ImageView` en `imgZoom`, este es mi código :

```
private View individual(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_image_zoom, container, false);
        final View pbr = v.findViewById(R.id.PhotoDetail_pbr_main);
        imgZoom = (ZoomImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.PhotoDetail_tiv_main);
        imgZoom.setTag(urlImage);
        imgZoom.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                View layTextPie = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.textViewFooter);
            }
        });
    Glide.with(inflater.getContext())
            .load(urlImage)
            .into(imgZoom);
        }
        return v;
    }
```

Obtengo el siguiente mensaje de error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You must not call setTag() on a
>   view Glide is targeting

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Basado en el mensaje de error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You must not call setTag() on a
>   view Glide is targeting

Por ahora usando **[Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/370)**, no permite agregar un tag a la vista en la cual se cargara la imagen:

```
 imgZoom.setTag(urlImage);
```

por lo cual eliminando esta línea resolví mi problema.

Answer (score 5):

El error menciona la linea que causa tu error, en este caso cuando invocas el metodo `setTag()` de tu `ImageView`

```
imgZoom.setTag(urlImage); //Eliminar o comentar esta linea
```

Al parecer piensan agregar ese "feature" en la versión 4 de Glide.

Más información:
https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/370